# Can Black Body Radiation occur from a material with zero dipole moment?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, thermal-radiation

Assume you have a material that is made of neutral molecules with zero dipole moment, even in all excited states. Would such a material emit black body radiation ?

Comment: would you count quadrupole or octopole radiation?

Comment: @hyportnex Hm, I must admit that I didn't consider higher moments of the multipole expansion. So  would a body emit like a black body as long as it can couple to the EM-field in any way ?

Comment: I am not sure about this at all... Anyhow, a quadrupole is a lousy radiator but can radiate, so something may come out of a vibrating/shaking ensemble of such sources.

Comment: You cannot have a "body" if there are no bonds for the atoms and molecules to make it into a body, i.e. energy levels in an electromagnetic binding, and those energy levels would be giving the bb radiation due to the temperature of the body (rotational and vibrational levels)

Comment: @annav Molecules certainly can have dark states when it comes to electronic state transitions. Is that not possible for the rotational/vibrational state manifold ? Does their existance necessitate a nonvanishing coupling matrix element ?

Comment: the multitude of molecules in a  solid body are bound and are in energy levels of the electric potential of the particular lattice. The models are collective quantum mechanical models, example http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Solids/band.html

Comment: you may wish to consider the broader case of "emit any radiation at all".  Black body radiation is a very restrictive subset of all radiation.